# Getting jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar on android for MOXy jaxb

Tags: android, maven, java-8, jaxb, android-studio-3.0

i am trying to get eclipseLink MOXy running on android (Android 7). But every time i try to add "jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar" as an Dependency i get this huge Error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\19.jar --output C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\20.jar --input C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\11.jar --input C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --output C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\2.jar --input C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\17.jar --output C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\18.jar --input C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --output C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\3.jar --input C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --output C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\17.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\18.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\19.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\20.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\dscholty\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 24 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

My gradle build looks like this: 
apply plugin:

```
'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dscholty.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'readme.html'
        exclude 'META-INF/eclipse.inf'
        exclude 'license.html'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/guava-24.0-jre.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.7.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.7.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar')
}
```

Is there a chance that anyone can help me out and get this running? I can not seem to find any good help on the internet on this.

Comment: Does JAXB work on Android at all?

Comment: i mean that is really the question. I am relatively new to this. If someone could explain that its not possible and tell me exactly why its not, this would be a huge help. Right now i can only "guess" why its not working.

Comment: Last time I asked, JAXB did not work on Android. But I'm not an Android dev so may be not up-to-date.

Comment: Do you know a reason to exactly why this is ?

Comment: Not really. My impression was it's because of annotations and reflection, but I don't know exactly.